# How to get binary dump of SQLite memory db

Tags: zend-framework, sqlite, memory, zend-db, dump

If i have code like this

```
$dbSL = Zend_Db::factory('pdo_sqlite', array('dbname'=>':memory:'));

$dbSL->query('CREATE TABLE ...');
$dbSL->query('CREATE TABLE ...');

...
```

After that i whant take binary dump of this SQLite db

Thx in advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this thread on Nabble](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Saving-a-memory-based-SQLite-database-to-disk-td44225.html).  You can use the [ATTACH](http://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) command to save a `:memory:` DB to disk, but if you're only working in memory to gain speed, they make a few suggestions about reducing error checking to gain speed as well.